# Does 8086 initiate a 1-byte code fetch when there's only 1 byte left in the prefetch queue?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, x86-16

I know that the 8086 architecture has a 6-byte prefetch queue.

My questions is, does the Bus Interface Unit fetch another byte-sized instruction as soon as one instruction is moved to the Execution Unit and space is free in the queue? Or does it wait for some specific number of bytes to be freed up before it starts fetching again?

Comment: did some research and found the answer. couldn't find anything related to my question on SO, so answering my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The BIU is programmed to fetch a new instruction whenever the queue has room for one (with the 8088) or two (with the 8086) additional bytes.

source: [http://ee.sharif.edu/~sakhtar3/articles/8086/8086%20Architecture.htm](http://ee.sharif.edu/%7Esakhtar3/articles/8086/8086%20Architecture.htm)

Comment: That makes sense.  Most 8086 instructions are 4 bytes or shorter, so letting it get down to that size is unlikely to immediately stall the next decode.  Aggressively starting a 1-byte fetch would be bad because memory itself isn't pipelined, and there might be more than 1 byte of space left before the fetch finishes, wasting fetch bandwidth (which was a bottleneck on 8086, although not nearly as much as 8088 apparently).  Also increases competition with data access, and push/pop/ret are common 1-byte instructions.